# Find the derivative of $\frac{3}{x} - \frac{x}{2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I must find the derivative for:
$\frac{3}{x} - \frac{x}{2}$

I know the answer is$ \frac{-3}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2}$

But I can't figure out why the 3 is negative and where the 1/2 came from

Any help please? Test tomorrow!

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{x} = x^{-1}$

Comment: $\frac {3}{x}-\frac {x}{2}=3x^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}x$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$3/x=3x^{-1}$ and when you take derivative use formula:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$$ and here $n=-1$  and that solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

We have the function $f(x)=\frac{3}{x}-\frac{x}{2}$, which can also be written $f(x)=3x^{-1}-\frac{1}{2}x$.

To find the derivative, apply the power rule $\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$ to each of the terms:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(3x^{-1})=3(-1)(x^{-2})=-3x^{-2}=-\frac{3}{x^2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{1}{2}x\right)=-\frac{1}{2}(1)x^0=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Adding the two terms together gives the desired solution: $$f'(x)=-\frac{3}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would help if you look at it this way:  $$(3)(\frac{1}{x})-(\frac{1}{2})(x) = (3)(x^{-1})-(\frac{1}{2})(x).$$